# What are all the ways that a PC can become immune to the frightened condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, immunities, fear

#### Question

I'm interested in ways to become permanently immune to the frightened condition. I hope this is considered a bounded list question and therefore on-topic.

I've so far only considered race- or class-features, feats, or magic items; I don't think there's anything else that's relevant, but if there's something else I've overlooked, ask me in the comments.

#### What I'm not looking for

- Unearthed Arcana content is acceptable, but **homebrew is not**, and **nor is third party material** (the Expanded Racial Feats gets a free pass though, because I didn't know that it was third party at the time - I've asked about that separately [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158298/35259));
- **Immunity only to specific creatures** such as per *protection from evil and good*, since I'm specifically interested in blanket immunity;
- Anything that involves **polymorphing** into something else;
- **Temporary effects or spells** (such as Mindless Rage, the level 6 Berserker Barbarian feature, which is only active while raging, or *protection from evil and good*);

To clarify, by temporary, I mean something that isn't passively indefinite. For example, a level 20 Berserker would still need to activate the rage continuously, and a spell would need to be recast continuously, whereas what I've listed below is "always on". If there were a spell that, once cast, lasted forever (excluding being dispelled; e.g. *[continual flame](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/continual-flame)*), that would be OK (I don't mind a one-time activation); this counts for magic items that need to be activated too.

#### What I've found already

These are the ways that I'm already aware of after looking into it myself:

- Aura of Courage (level 10 Paladin, any archetype);
- Raven's Shield (level 10 Warlock, Raven Queen archetype from [this UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_wizrd_wrlck_uav2_i48nf.pdf));
- Touch of Sess'inek (Lizardfolk-specific feat from the Expanded Racial Feats);
- [These magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=6&filter-effect-subtype=198&filter-has-charges=) (at time of writing, this D&DBeyond search lists 4 items, although the Banner of Krig Rune only lasts for 10 minutes, so is temporary and therefore doesn't count - thanks to @Medix2 for pointing that out);

Are there any I've missed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100288/discussion-on-question-by-nathans-what-are-all-the-ways-that-a-pc-can-become-imm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Artifacts can have this as a random [minor beneficial property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#MinorBeneficialProperties):

  > While attuned to the artifact, you can’t be charmed or frightened.
- [Blackrazor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/blackrazor) which does not appear on your D&D Beyond Search
- [Fungal Body](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#FungalBody-274976) (level 14 Druid, Circle of Spores archetype)