# What are all the ways to damage more than one creature in a single attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, targeting

The [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell states:

> [...] Regardless of the creature's abilities or magic items, it can't make more than one melee or ranged attack during its turn [...]

I realized that one way around this restriction is to use attacks that target multiple enemies. For example [the Hunter Ranger's Whirlwind Strike and Volley features](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149681). The answer to the linked question explains Volley which Jeremy Crawford, lead game designer, [has tweeted](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/512336707828457473) matches the intended reading:

> Like Whirlwind Attack, Volley is a single attack with multiple attack rolls.

Regarding Whirlwind Attack, the Sage Advice Compendium explicitly states:

> [...] Whirlwind Attack is unusual, in that it’s a single attack with multiple attack rolls [...]

Another feature I've found that does this is the Battle Master Fighter's Sweeping Maneuver:

> When you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to damage another creature **with the same attack**. Choose another creature within 5 feet of the original target and within your reach. If the original attack roll would hit the second creature, it takes damage equal to the number you roll on your superiority die. The damage is of the same type dealt by the original attack.

Here a single attack is targeting multiple creatures and thus it could be used while under the effects of *slow*.

---

There is also the *green-flame blade* spell:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack's normal effects, and green fire leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it. The second creature takes fire damage equal to your spellcasting ability modifier. This spell's damage increases when you reach higher levels.

And there is also the *ice knife* spell as well.

Are there other examples of things like this, where a single attack damages multiple creatures? Note I do not care about situational things such as "if the enemy has *warding bond* I would damage two creatures". I want these to be options available to the attacker, dependant only up to *where* the enemies are (and also their type if that even matters)

Comment: If this question is too broad, suggestions on how to narrow it would be appreciated. I just thought the list would be utterly small.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I don’t think it’s too broad but I do think it’s a “do work for me that I don’t want to” question that suits the site poorly. If we had [a format](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) where people could just add the one thing they knew and a list could be crowdsourced that way, it would work better; this auestion, asked here, needs one person to do all the reading and compiling, which is just grunt work that anyone could do rather than leveraging expertise. (Re-reading that, it does make me wonder if “grunt work” Qs would work as CWs…)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah I'm just unsure what do in cases like this or https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158290. At the very least I have already gone through what *I* could find and the examples I give are the only things I found.

Comment: @MarkWells It allows one to damage multiple enemies while avoiding the clause in the *slow* spell that you can only make one attack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Class Features

- #### Battle Master's Maneuvers

  This feature option allows an attack to damage a second creature. The attack only has one target, but its attack roll is used to determine whether the second creature takes damage.

  > **Sweeping Attack.** When you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to damage another creature with the same attack. Choose another creature within 5 feet of the original target and within your reach. If the original attack roll would hit the second creature, it takes damage equal to the number you roll on your superiority die. The damage is of the same type dealt by the original attack.
- #### College of Sword's Blade Fourish

  This feature option allows an attack to damage multiple creatures. The attack only has one target, but the extra damage (which is part of the attack's damage) is dealt to multiple creatures.

  > **Slashing Flourish.** You can expend one use of your Bardic Inspiration to cause the weapon to deal extra damage to the target you hit and to any other creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of you. The damage equals the number you roll on the Bardic Inspiration die.
- #### Hunter's Multiattack

  These feature options allow you to make a single attack that targets multiple creatures, by making several attack rolls.

  > **Volley.** You can use your action to make a ranged attack against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon's range. You must have ammunition for each target, as normal, and you make a separate attack roll for each target.
  >   **Whirlwind Attack.** You can use your action to make a melee attack against any number of creatures within 5 feet of you, with a separate attack roll for each target.

## Spells

- #### *Chaos bolt*

  This spell allows you to make a single attack that targets multiple creatures, by making several attack rolls.

  > You hurl an undulating, warbling mass of chaotic energy at one creature in range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 2d8 + 1d6 damage. [...] If you roll the same number on both d8s, the chaotic energy leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice within 30 feet of it. Make a new attack roll against the new target, and make a new damage roll, which could cause the chaotic energy to leap again.
- #### *Eldritch blast*

  This spell allows you to make a single attack that targets multiple creatures, by making several attack rolls.

  > A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.
  >   The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th level. You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make a separate attack roll for each beam.

## Features that are unclear

- #### Sorcerer's Twinned Spell

  When you twin a spell that makes an attack (i.e. *fire bolt*), it's unclear whether you make two attacks each against one target, one attack with one attack roll against two targets, or one attack with two attack rolls each against one target.

  > When you cast a spell that doesn't have a range of self and is incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell's current level, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell's level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

## Honorable Mentions that do not qualify

- #### Arcane Archer's Curving Shot

  This feature allows you to choose a a second target with for one attack, but the attack cannot damage both targets.

  > At 7th level, you learn how to direct an errant arrow toward a new target. When you make an attack roll with a magic arrow and miss, you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.
- #### Arcane Archer's Arcane Shot Options

  This feature option's attack only interracts with its target, not the secondary creatures, and the secondary damage is a distinct effect that is not part of the attack. Hence, the attack does not damage more than one creature.

  > **Bursting Arrow.** You imbue your arrow with force energy drawn from the school of evocation. The energy detonates after your attack. Immediately after the arrow hits the creature, the target and all other creatures within 10 feet of it take 2d6 force damage each.
- #### *Green-flame blade*

  The spell's attack only interracts with its target, not the secondary creatures, and the secondary damage is a distinct effect that is not part of the attack. Hence, the attack does not damage more than one creature.

  > As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack's normal effects, and green fire leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it. The second creature takes fire damage equal to your spellcasting ability modifier

Comment: Your EB bit does not seem correct. Each EB is a separate attack, so it's more like a Fighter getting more attacks with the Attack action at certain levels.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast eldritch blast has the same wording as whirlwind attack: one attack, multiple attack rolls. Hence it must behave like whirlwind attack, not extra attack

Comment: I would suggest the Ice Knife spell as an honorable mention. Pretty similar to Bursting Arrow.

Comment: I disagree about *eldritch blast*, *chaos bolt*, and Twinned Spell; I've made my case in [my answer to the question "Does the Slow spell limit the number of Eldritch Blast beams?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159269/33569).

Answer (score -3):

One that immediately comes to mind is Eldritch Blast:

> The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th level. You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make a separate attack roll for each beam.

This is one spell attack that could target multiple creatures

Comment: Actually *Eldritch blast* is one spell causing multiple spell attacks to occur, there is a separate attack roll for each beam

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As the quote itself says, you make a separate attack roll for each beam; it's one spell, but multiple attacks. (If every spell that involved multiple attack rolls were considered a single "attack", Whirlwind Attack wouldn't be unusual at all.)

Comment: @V2Blast But the relevant parts of eldritch blast read very similar to volley "make a ranged spell attack ... Make a separate attack roll for each beam". Not every spell is worded like that

Comment: I've made my case in [my answer to the question "Does the Slow spell limit the number of Eldritch Blast beams?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159269/33569).