# What type of content is the XGtE Expanded Racial Feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, content-identification, dnd-beyond, dms-guild

This came out of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158290/35259) when discussing in the comments what is and is not allowed.

For some context, David Coffron said in the comments of the above question:

> [...] Does unofficial, published content (i.e. 3rd party content) count for your question? [...]
>
> [... *I answered with basically "what even is XGtE Expanded Racial Feats?"* ...]
>
> [...] It does have WoTC approval (according to the document itself), but I don't think its considered official. Bit of a weird case. XGtE is an official book, but the expanded feats are not MWICT.

So, does the XGtE Expanded Racial Feats have WotC's approval, is it considered official or unofficial, 3rd party or what? What is it exactly?

Comment: What makes you think it is "less official" than the PHB? I do not see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Related: [Where do I find the “official” rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836) - "officiality" is *not* a defined thing

Comment: @Szega The comments in the other question have confused me, so if you can point at something and say "this is what makes it official", that would help me. Basically, assume I know nothing, and that I only understand what's in a physical hardcover book, because that is kinda where I'm at tbh. I'm pretty much only aware of what's listed in the answer to Medix2's linked question, and don't understand how stuff outside of that fits with it.

Comment: Related: [Is D&D Beyond an official rules source?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114911/35259), contains some interesting references as to what is and is not considered official.

Comment: Very related: [How are materials on DMs Guild classified?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144825)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### It should be treated like all other third-party, unofficial content on DM's Guild.

*Expanded Racial Feats* was authored by Adam "BadEye" Bradford, who leads the D&D Beyond team. It was offered as a preorder bonus for the digital *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* on D&D Beyond. It was later moved to the [homebrew section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/feats?filter-name=&filter-description=&filter-author=BadEye&filter-author-previous=BadEye&filter-author-symbol=23611187&filter-rating=) of D&D Beyond (accessible by all), and offered as a [PDF](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/226194/Expanded-Racial-Feats) on DM's Guild, where it is labeled as "Community Content" (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/144938) for an explanation of the different types of content on DM's Guild).

The purpose of the document is to supplement *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* by providing racial feats for races that are not part of the PHB, as *Xanathar's* provides racial feats for the PHB races only.

It was never published by Wizards of the Coast and should be treated the same as other third-party, unofficial content on DM's Guild. It should also not be referred to with XGtE as part of its name, as that is misleading and not how it is named on DMs Guild.